# Wrong page height with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a page divided into five `DIVs`, everyone with `FLOAT: LEFT` to put them on the same page in five columns.
i have given an `HEIGHT: 100%` and until now all is perfect. But if i put on the page something longer than the height above, i have used the following code:

```
var i;
  // there five divs with id div1, div2, div3, div4, div5
  for (i=1; i<=5; i++)
    $( "#div" + i ).height($( document ).height());
```

But on the bottom of the page remains always a blank space, the total height is less than the document height! how to resolve it? i've tried also to assign a MIN-HEIGHT: 100% to every div but nothing!

Comment: Please post your markup and CSS, and also consider putting together a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to do window viewport height:

```
$( "#div" + i ).height($( window ).height());
```

---

If you are using height in percentage like div height to 100% then make sure to have:

```
html,body{height: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

`$(document).outerHeight()`

instead of

`$( document ).height()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of what you're asking, but why not do this with CSS?

Have you tried using height: 100vh?

Here's a reference to viewport height/width.

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css-viewport-units/